# How to position many canvas elements at particular position with loop

Tags: javascript, html, loops, canvas, html5-canvas

Below you can see that there are three canvas elements. I want to position them in a horizontal line with exactly 400px of a gap in between them. I can do that manually, but it gets impractical if I want to draw 100 such elements. How can I solve the problem with a loop?

```
let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

let c = canvas.getContext('2d');

c.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
c.fillRect(500, 100, 100, 100);
c.fillRect(900, 100, 100, 100);
```

This is what I have tried

```
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

    c.beginPath();
    let x = 100; // { x = Math.random() * window.innerWidth }  works 
    x = x + 400;
    console.log(x);
    let y = 100;

    c.fillRect(x, y, 100, 100);

}
```

All the canvas elements will be separated by 400px and will be in the same horizontal line

Comment: `let w = 100; let gap = 400; for(let x = 0; x < c.width; x+= w + gap){ c.fillRect(x, 100, 100, 100);}`

Comment: @enxaneta thanks, but it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question

```
for(let x = 100; x < 1000; x += 400) {
    console.log(x);
    c.fillRect(x, 100, 100, 100);
}
```

so, in the beginning "x" is starting in a position which is 100px away from the left. 
My target was to draw exactly 3 elements, so I am looping the script till " x < 1000", and in each loop, the x will increment "400px" from the previous value.

If I write "x < 1500" then I will get 4 figures, because

value of x in

1st Loop: 100

2nd Loop: 500

3rd Loop: 900

4th Loop: 1300.

......end of Loop, as in 5th loop "x" is greater than 1500